# How to make flash messages clickable? Using ember-cli-flash

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember 1.13

Suppose user sent some message and they see a flash message saying 'Your message was successfully sent. *View message*'. So when the user clicks on 'View message' inside the flash message, they should be redirected to that message's page. How do we do that using ember-cli-flash addon?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is [answer](https://github.com/poteto/ember-cli-flash/issues/58).

It is the same issue on github.

You should define your custom options for message(i did it in controller):

```
controller.get('flashMessages').add({
          template: 'template-for-flash-message',
          type: 'danger',
          message: 'your message',
          userId: user.id
        });
```

In `template-for-flash-message.hbs`:

```
<p>Your message was successfully sent. {{#link-to 'messages.show' flash.userId}} View message. {{/link-to}}</p>
```